# Pentaho scheduled PDF reporting

Tags: mysql, pdf, scheduled-tasks, reporting, pentaho

I am quite new in Pentaho and don't seem to understand some basics. My company has a MySQL database (readable) with which we want to print reports daily and annually for the employees to access. I have been looking at tools such as Jaspersoft. But I also stumbled upon Pentaho which has nice reviews. Nevertheless, I installed "Pentaho Report Designer" but didn't manage to do scheduled PDF printing jobs. I saw that for this I have to download the whole Suite (which is quite huge). Does anybody have a solution - is it possible to download only the User Console and the reporting tool? I searched for a while on Google but didn't manage to find the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind - I didn't look carefully enough. By downloading the community edition , I can chose directly which modules I want and schedule tasks through the server with the user access panel.

Comment: i also facing the same problem which you explain but i am new i dont know how to start please read my question and answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174022/fetch-data-from-remote-database-every-hour