# Fetch Data From Remote Database Every Hour

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-ctools

Yesterday i Download

- Pentaho BI Server
- Data Integration
- Report Designer

Than I connect report designer to the remote database and fetch table and draw chart of that data successfully.
My Question is ,I want to run that file (which i create in report designing ) every hour by fetching the new data from remote database
can you please guide me step by step how to do it because i am new in all those stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer My own Question. So In order to schedule Job in Data Integration You Have To Follow these Steps

**Step 1: Create Transformation**

Create Transformation which you want to run like in my case i fetch the data from database and than write it to file.

**Step 2: Create Job**

Create Job and run above transformation according to your desired interval

Answer (score 0):

In Pentaho you would create a Transformation or a Job in Data Integration to fetch data from the remote database, and then use the report created with Report Designer to visualize the data that you have downloaded with Data Integration.

Comment: Jobln or Job there is no such type of option called Jobln what will be the best method to fetch data job or transformation

Comment: sorry. Typo. The best method will depend on your data. Check the FAQ: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Beginners+FAQ#BeginnersFAQ-What%27sthedifferencebetweentransformationsandjobs%3F

Comment: thanks dear link help me is it possible that i send data from DI to RD file and than it genrate report automatically

Comment: What you normally do is to store the data locally, in a dataware house/database and then connect RD to that.

Comment: i want to fetch data from server every hour than create the report of that data

Comment: I successfully connected the database and fetch data the problem is how to do job scheduling and how to send receive data to report desiging  file to create report

Comment: For scheduling, either use Pentaho's scheduler, or use cron to schedule the job. For report design file you need to put the data somewhere it can find and use the data.

Comment: i think cron on server side i want to use local machine for that

Comment: I also want to do the same thing on schedule basis but i want that report to send via email as attachment prefer PDF not zip file. can you please help me how to do